# «Не вприглядку» — слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография, частица-не, наречия

*Точно бы получил согласие, вон девушка от одного имени алеет, как маков цвет. Да какая девушка! Словно солнце не под хмурыми облаками прячется, а по земле ходит. Это поначалу да **(не)вприглядку** Пеппи может неинтересной показаться.*

Есть наречие "вприглядку", и очень хочется "не" написать с ним слитно. Если очень хочется, то можно? Как думаете, уважаемые знатоки русского?

Comment: Так а что вам запрещает написать слитно? Всё правильно!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, здесь "не вприглядку" использовано в несвойственном ему значении.
Как я понимаю и как следует из приведенных Jasmin и Риммой примеров, противоположостью "вприглядку" является что-то **большее**, чем просто смотреть.
Любовь не вприглядку - это отношения во всей их полноте:

> Но в непогоду срывай плод прежде, чем он обвис, и под большими, часто моргающими глазами невесты тень, выдающая, что из неё уже испили любовь не вприглядку. [В. Г. Распутин. Новая профессия (1998)]

Вы ведь не это хотели передать?

Я вот написанное слитно *невприглядку*  —  хоть такое написание нигде не зафиксировано — я интуитивно воспринимаю именно как "не приглядевшись".

И, попутно, еще одно замечание. Солнце может оказаться ПОД облаками только на восходе и на закате. А прячется оно ЗА облаками. Я бы допустил также поэтическое *прячется МЕЖДУ облаками, В облаках, СРЕДИ облаков*.

Comment: Какие тонкие и точные замечания! Вы верно уловили, что хотел передать автор. От автора особая благодарность еще и за солнце. Наконец-то он понял, что именно хотел сказать, и слегка переформулировал. «Невприглядку» оставил.

Comment: Елена, должен предупредить, что насчет  "невприглядку" решение Ваше рискованное. Кроме интуиции ничего поставить на эту чашу весов не могу.

Comment: Две интуиции на одной чаше весов - это уже что-то. И вообще, я люблю шампанское.

Answer (score 3):

1)  Наречие ***вприглядку***  согласно словарю имеет ограниченное значение, в то же время это значение может быть расширено или изменено.

**ВПРИГЛЯДКУ**, нареч. Шутл. Без сахара, только глядя на сахар (ср. вприкуску, внакладку). Пить чай в.

Примеры: **Не вприглядку** пьет, да еще потчует, значит, не скряга, значит, едва ли польстится. [М. А. Алданов. Истоки. Части 9-17 (1942-1946)]

Но в непогоду срывай плод прежде, чем он обвис, и под большими, часто моргающими глазами невесты тень, выдающая, что из неё уже испили любовь **не вприглядку**. [В. Г. Распутин. Новая профессия (1998)]

2) Э**то поначалу да не вприглядку (= не всматриваясь) Пеппи может неинтересной показаться.**

В приведенном примере  значение тоже изменено, и **лучше писать НЕ раздельно,** так как слитное написание в текстах вообще не встречается (ни в каком значении).

Answer (score 3):

*Пусть всё это уйдёт безвозвратно:

Жить хочу без цепей и оков,

Чтоб любить от души — **не вприглядку**,

И не быть в списке чьих-то грехов.*
[И. Буланова](http://slova.textologia.ru/definit/vpriglyadku/?q=657&n=1381)

*Говорили, например, что чай Бродский пьет **не вприглядку**, как бедняк, не вприкуску, как человек с достатком, не внакладку, как богач, а подают ему головку сахара с отверстием на макушке, в эту дыру он наливает чай и таким образом пьет.*
[А. Рыбаков. Тяжелый песок](https://books.google.ee/books?id=vbLMAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT180&lpg=PT180&dq=%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D1%83%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%BF%D1%8C%D0%B5%D1%82&source=bl&ots=xdH3Mx18Jr&sig=KIqntjwHD0kLlioIgDt65hUk1ss&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLkc3nqL_ZAhWIbVAKHX_RDgcQ6AEILTAB#v=onepage&q=%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D1%83%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%BF%D1%8C%D0%B5%D1%82&f=false)

*Сейчас **не вприглядку**, как раньше, не по наитию, а совершенно точно — по анализам, тестам, по записям игровой деятельности известно состояние любого игрока.*
[Н. Старостин. Звезды большого футбола](https://books.google.ee/books?id=LrE8DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT230&lpg=PT230&dq=%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D1%83%20%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0&source=bl&ots=7sg290L9CH&sig=Hccku6c2fBhdjNlqTwtdveKUOq8&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwisqNbxqr_ZAhVQKlAKHd0tCuEQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D1%83%20%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0&f=false)

Стоит отметить, что и с другими подобными наречиями — ***в***присядку, **в**припрыжку, **в**развалку — **"не" пишется отдельно**.

*Телеса добросовестно крутились, вертелись, чуть ли **не вприсядку** шли* (А. Валентинов); *Я перебросил через плечо сумку с невеликими пожитками и едва **не вприпрыжку** побежал за военными...* (А. Мартьянов); *Стремглав, а **не вразвалку** — как бравые провинившиеся солдаты, желающие искупить!* (П. Альшевский)